# How to select specific DIV in web API response (html)

Tags: c#, html, web-scraping

I have an API that can pass a search query to a web site that I use to lookup products.  I use the catalog number to obtain the device identifier.  The response that is returned is HTML, and I need to extract one line from the HTML to write to a file.  Is it possible to select a specific div in a web API?

My goal is to eventually loop over each product search, pull the one line I need, and then write it to an Excel file.

Here is an example of the API searching a product, and the response:

[image: API working]

Here is the single line of code that I need to extract out of the response, I then want to concatenate it to the URL and write the whole link out with each specific device identifier:

[image: Line of code I need]

I hope this makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

This is a parsing problem, and since the file/content you want to extract from is HTML, it would be a straightforward task.

You have three main steps to get this done.

1. Parse the content, whether it's on the web, or downloaded file.
2. Use a selector to get the "a" tag you're looking for.
3. Extract the URL from the "href" attribute from the "a" tag.

I see you're using C#, so I would recommend [this library](https://html-agility-pack.net/select-nodes), you will use its parser to parse the file, then the selector along with a CSS selector, to get your data.

Let me know if you still need more details.

Comment: Thank you so much for that! Now my next question is how to pass the HTML through the parser from the response?  Would I need to download it, then upload it? (write/read)?

Comment: I'm not sure how are you getting the response, but if you can store it in a string variable, then you can use this https://html-agility-pack.net/from-string feature and parse it using the from-string parser using the same library, which would then allow you to select the data you want.